# How can I create buttons, labels and textfields using string arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I have to create a JFrame similar to the picture below, using only String arrays for the buttons, labels, and textfields. I should also use the ActionListener for handling events for the buttons. And the application should also generate a file (output.txt) with the user data. I will upload a photo of the problem to make it clear. you will also find the code that I have so far. the code does not open any window when I run it.

```
    public class PizzaShop extends JFrame {

    String s1 []= {"First Name","Family","Telephone","Total Cost"};
    String s2[][]= {{"Base","Chicken","Meat"},{"Mozarella","Cheddar","Onion"},{"Tomato","Mushroom","Olive"}};
    JLabel jl[]= new JLabel [4];
    TextField tl[]=new TextField [4];
    JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];
    
    public PizzaShop () {

        for (int i=0; i<s1.length; i++) 
            jl[i]=new JLabel (s1[i]);
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
                buttons[i][j]=new JButton (s2[i][j]);
        
        // layout 
        GridLayout layout= new GridLayout (4,5);
        
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) 
            add(jl[i]);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) 
            add(tl[i]);
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
                add(buttons[i][j]);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        PizzaShop order = new PizzaShop();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should be using `JTextField`, not TextField *the code does not open any window when I run it.* - what error messages to you get?

Comment: I did not get any error messages

Comment: Did you look at your console? I get a NullPointerException.on: `add(tl[i]);`. Also, why do you loops only go to 3, when you create an array of 4 items?

Comment: The loops are just a mistake by me. And yes I see the error now in my console but I don't understand why and how to fix it.

Comment: The instructions say "use a JFrame", not extend a JFrame.  Looking at the GUI, there are 4 JPanels, in the BorderLayout positions NORTH, EAST. SOUTH, and WEST.  The WEST and EAST JPanels use a GridLayout of (0, 2) and (0, 3), respectively.  JButtons hold an action command as well as the display text, so the action command would be a good place to put the price of each item.  That'll make the ActionListener much easier to code.

Comment: @HessaAlraeesi, *I see the error now in my console but I don't understand why* - defining an array is not the same as adding items to the array. You never create a JTextField to add to the array.